# sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main not recognizable

Tags: java, jar, jmap

I have the line 'sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(args);' in my code. Eclipse is giving error saying the class is not identified. So, I tried to download sun.tools jar. But I could not find this jar anywhere!

I am not sure what to include to remove this error. Please  help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `sun.tools.jmap.JMap` is not part of standard JRE. This is used by the out of box tools shipped with JDK.

The class `sun.tools.jmap.JMap` is in `<JAVA_HOME>/lib/tools.jar`. Jars in this folder are used by the tools in `<JAVA_HOME>/bin` folder. For example,  `sun.tools.jmap.JMap` is used by a tool `jmap.exe`

For your code to compile in Eclipse, include `<JAVA_HOME>/lib/tools.jar` in the classpath.